# Finding roots of higher degree polynomials with complex coefficients using gsl library in C

Tags: c, complex-numbers, polynomials, gsl, coefficients

I have a quinitc equation to solve. It is a part of a long calculation. I have a code in C and I wanted to use the gsl for doing calculations. In particular, I want to use the function `gsl_complex_poly_complex_eval` but I am having trouble in defining its attributes. Following is a simple code I want to use.

```
#include<studio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_poly.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_complex.h>
int
main (void)
{

double omgo,omgM,omge,omgA;
double g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6;

omgM = 5000;
omgo = 490;
omgA=9.97;
omge=0.00035;
g1 = 1.0;
g2 = 2*omge;
g3 = (omgA*omgA+omge*omge+2*omgM*omgM+4*omgo*omgo);
g4 = -2*omge*(omgA*omgA+omgM*omgM+4*omgo*omgo);
g5 = (cpow(omgM,4.0)+omgA*omgA(omge*omge+omgM*omgM)+4*cpow(omge,2.0)*cpow(omgo,2));
g6 = omgA*omgA*omge*omgM*omgM;
gsl_complex a[6],z;
a[0] = -I*g6;
a[1] = g5;
a[2] = -I*g4;
a[3] = -g3;
a[4] = -2*I*g2;
a[5] = g1;
gsl_complex_poly_complex_eval(a,6,z);
print("%.30lf, %.30lf\n",creal(z),cimag(z));
return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors like:

```
quintic_roots.c: In function ‘main’:
quintic_roots.c:28:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘complex double’
  a[0] = -I*g6;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:29:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘double’
  a[1] = g5;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:30:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘complex double’
  a[2] = -I*g4;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:31:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘double’
  a[3] = -g3;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:32:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘complex double’
  a[4] = -2*I*g2;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:33:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘double’
  a[5] = g1;
       ^
quintic_roots.c:38:36: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘cimag’
  printf ("%.30lf, %.30lf\n", cimag(z),creal(z));
                                    ^
In file included from quintic_roots.c:3:0:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/cmathcalls.h:127:1: note: expected ‘complex double’ but argument is of type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’
 __MATHDECL (_Mdouble_,cimag, (_Mdouble_complex_ __z));
 ^
quintic_roots.c:38:45: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘creal’
  printf ("%.30lf, %.30lf\n", cimag(z),creal(z));
                                             ^
In file included from quintic_roots.c:3:0:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/cmathcalls.h:130:1: note: expected ‘complex double’ but argument is of type ‘gsl_complex {aka struct <anonymous>}’
 __MATHDECL (_Mdouble_,creal, (_Mdouble_complex_ __z));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your attempt, together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Please take a look at e.g. [this `gsl_poly_complex_eval` reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/poly.html#c.gsl_poly_complex_eval). Your arguments does not match the declaration shown for `gsl_poly_complex_eval`.

Comment: Your best friend when dealing with libraries that you don't know is documentation. Here is the documentation for [gsl-lib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/). You can read function declarations there, and format your code accordingly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I know that but I don't know how exactly to define them. Thank you.

Comment: @MohithReddy I can't follow it. There is no example provided for those declarations, for that particular function. Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of the first argument to the `gsl_poly_complex_eval` function? What is the type of the second argument? What is the type of the third argument? You have to make sure that the values you pass are the same type. So in your code, what is the type of `a`? What is the type of `z`? What do you need to change to make sure that the types of `a` and `z` match with the types needed for the `gsl_poly_complex_eval` function?

Comment: @GauravMaurya The errors you attached or not the recent one, there is no ``b`` declared and you perfectly placed ``;`` before return. Pls, attach the recent compiler errors or warnings. Moreover, you are using ``gsl_poly_complex_eval`` and errors are of ``gsl_complex_poly_complex_eval``

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have change the code; please see the edits; I am making mistake in defining the variables. I would be a great help, if someone code make changes in the code attached above so that definition of variables is correct. Since I am a beginner I won't know. Thank you.

Comment: @MohithReddy Sorry. I have made the changes. Now one could see the mistakes in the code, that is, definition of variables according to gsl requirements. Thank you.

Comment: @MohithReddy Thank you so much. I will follow the documentation closely.

Comment: @GauravMaurya Since you are new to the community, please give a refresh to the link -- [how to accept answers and what comments to make](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many changes are made, all as directed by [libgsl-documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/). You need to understand the power of documentation, I never used `libgsl`, but here I am writing code using it, all because of documentation.

quintic_roots.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<complex.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_poly.h>
#include<gsl/gsl_complex.h>
int
main (void)
{

    double omgo,omgM,omge,omgA;
    double g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6;

    omgM = 5000;
    omgo = 490;
    omgA=9.97;
    omge=0.00035;
    g1 = 1.0;
    g2 = 2*omge;
    g3 = (omgA*omgA+omge*omge+2*omgM*omgM+4*omgo*omgo);
    g4 = -2*omge*(omgA*omgA+omgM*omgM+4*omgo*omgo);
    g5 = (cpow(omgM,4.0)+omgA*omgA*(omge*omge+omgM*omgM)+4*cpow(omge,2.0)*cpow(omgo,2));
    g6 = omgA*omgA*omge*omgM*omgM;

    gsl_complex *a = (gsl_complex*) calloc(6, sizeof(gsl_complex));

    GSL_SET_IMAG(a, -g6);
    GSL_SET_REAL(a+1, g5);
    GSL_SET_IMAG(a+2, -g4);
    GSL_SET_REAL(a+3, -g3);
    GSL_SET_IMAG(a+4, -2*g2);
    GSL_SET_REAL(a+5, g1);

    gsl_complex z;

    GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&z, 1, 1);

    gsl_complex res = gsl_complex_poly_complex_eval(a,6,z);

    printf("%.15lf, %.15lf\n",GSL_REAL(res),GSL_IMAG(res));
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation

```
gcc quintic_roots.c -lgsl  -lm
```

Output

```
625002586907152.250000000000000, 625002382231741.375000000000000
```

The output is for `z = 1 + 1i`, pls modify z according to your input.